# Ant build encoding error with TestNG DataProvider

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, ant, testng-dataprovider

My problem is this:
In eclipse, I'd made a selenium test class which takes some parameters from an xls file. The parameters contains characters with accent, for example "é", "á"...
So i set eclipse Text File Encoding to ISO-8859-2, because this set contains all the characters what my language use, after this its run perfectly.

Than i made a testng.xml, and its also works fine if i run as TestNG Suite.

After that i made an ant build.xml, cause i want to make XSLT reports, and also want to run the tests in jenkins with ant invoke...  but when i run the ant build in eclipse or in jenkins, it can't handle/dont recognize the accent... everything works fine, except this.

I tried a few things like setting the xml (both of testng.xml and build.xml) encoding to ISO-8859-2, in ant build.xml the javac encoding  to ISO-8859-2, i set the ANT_OPTS to -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-2, but it don't want to work.

Is anybody have any clue, what should i try to set?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

In my Ant `build.xml` I am using something like this

```
<target name="test">
    <testng>
        <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=cp1252" /> 
    </testng>
</target>
```

Could you try this with `ISO-8859-2`instead of `cp1252`?

[See documentation for further info.](http://testng.org/doc/ant.html)